# Not able to get ResultSet value into String array?

Tags: java

```
String query = "select email from emp_select";
Statement stmt;

try {

  DB db=new DB(); 
  db.connect();
  stmt = (Statement) db.conn.createStatement(); // DB is connected here              

  ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(query);
  ResultSetMetaData rsmd = rs.getMetaData();

  int numberOfColumns = rsmd.getColumnCount();

  for (int i = 1; i <= numberOfColumns; i++) {
    if (i > 1)
        System.out.print(",  ");
  }
  System.out.println("");

  while (rs.next()) {
    for (int i = 1; i <= numberOfColumns; i++) {
        if (i > 1)
            System.out.print(",  ");

        String columnValue = rs.getString(i);
        name[i]=columnValue;
        System.out.println(name[i]);          //Everything executes well till here
    }
  }
  stmt.close();
} catch(Exception ex) {}

for (int i = 1; i < name.length; i++) {
    System.out.println(name[i]);   // why it gives null value here ?
}
```

Comment: Where do you declare the `name` array?

Comment: Btw: given your requirements a 1-dimensional array does not seem to make sense...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was wondering is this what you really want :

```
while (rs.next()) {
    for (int i = 1; i <= numberOfColumns; i++) {
        if (i > 1)
            System.out.print(",  ");

        String columnValue = rs.getString(i);
        name[i]=columnValue;
        System.out.println(name[i]);          //Everything executes well till here
    }
  }
```

Here what is happening is , the while loop starts, now for loop begins execution, now inside the for loop you are giving all elements of name array the same value i.e. rs.getString(i), but your query returns only one column for your rs, i.e. email (but you coding in your for loop something like names[2] = rs.getString(2), name[3] = rs.getString(3), but here there is nothing other than rs.getString(1)). Seems like what you should do is this, that might can give you expected results

```
for (int i = 1; i <= numberOfColumns; i++) {
        if (i > 1)
            System.out.print(",  ");
        if (rs.next()) // hope this works, not sure (but it does works for me at the click of a button, when used through Swing Events)
        {
            String columnValue = rs.getString(1);// Since only one thing is being returned by your rs object.
            name[i]=columnValue;
            System.out.println(name[i]);          //Everything executes well till here
        }
    }
```

Hopefully this might can solve.

Regards

Comment: Thank u sooo much i figures the problem it was like the value of "i" in for loop was always 1 so i used another variable for the array like "name[j]" . It worked properly .. Thanks once again

Comment: @user1151442 : Your Welcome. Happy to know it worked for you.  Regards

Answer (score 0):

okay let me rephrase this by this version of your code :

```
String query = "select email from emp_select";
Statement stmt;

try {

  DB db=new DB(); 
  db.connect();
  stmt = (Statement) db.conn.createStatement(); // DB is connected here              

  ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(query);
  ResultSetMetaData rsmd = rs.getMetaData();

  int numberOfColumns = rsmd.getColumnCount();
  List<String[]> names = new ArrayList<String[]>();
  String[] name=null; //assuming here you have only Varchar cols

  while (rs.next()) {
    name = new String[numberOfColumns];
    for (int i = 0; i <= numberOfColumns; i++)
    {
        name[i]=rs.getString(i);
    }
    names.add(name);
  }
  stmt.close();
} catch(Exception ex) {
    ex.printStackTrace();
}
for(String[] colResults : names)
{
   for (int i = 0; i < colResults.length; i++) {
       System.out.println(colResults[i]);
   }
}
```

Comment: i ve initialized it like String name[]=new String[100]; and it has Global scope

Comment: Global Scope in the Sense U can access it through out the Program

Answer (score 0):

I guess it's not "giving null" for every element of the name array. It's probably giving null because you have more elements in your name array than there are columns in your result set, or because the last row of your result set actually contains null values (you're throwing array all the rows except the last one).

Side notes:

- array indices in Java start from 0. Not putting anything in the first element of an array is questionable
- you should NEVER ignore exceptions like you're doing. If you can't handle a SQLException in this method, then it should be thrown by the method, not ignored.
- resultsets, statements and connections should be closed, in a finally block.

Comment: actually it returns null for all elements but then gives the last returned value for the ResultSet along with null !

Comment: You have a one-dimensional array to store several rows, each containing several columns. How do you intend this to work. Your code only stores the last row of the result set in your array, since at every row of the result set, it overwrites what was stored at the previous iteration.